# Using spring to connect to mysql, how to mimick connection pool?

Tags: java, mysql, spring

I'm using spring to connect to mysql currently.

I'm thinking of moving to simply servlets and drop spring as I don't need 99% of spring's functionality.

What do you suggest I use to get connection pooling functionality?  Is there a mysql connection pool that is framework independent?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Even if you don't need 99% of Spring's features you can still use Spring JDBC which by itself is worthwhile.  You don't need the whole Spring infrastructure to use it either - you can drop it in and use it by itself...no DI required. I have a coworker who is using [Stripes](http://www.stripesframework.org/display/stripes/Home) as his app's framework but uses Spring JDBC for database access.

You don't say what your container is (e.g. Tomcat, JBoss, etc) but there are several container independent connection pools to choose from, such as [DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/), [c3p0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0/), [BoneCP](http://jolbox.com/).  If you're using Tomcat 7 it ships with a new connection pool called [The Tomcat JDBC Connection Pool](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html) (I guess their marketing budget was cut :) ).

We just switched from DBCP to Tomcat's connection pool and it works great.  We haven't run any benchmarks on it but haven't run into any issues yet either.

I recommend sticking with Spring JDBC even if you use another connection pool, just for the database connection/statement management, disconnected result set, and "free" prepared statements (Spring JDBC creates prepared statements under the hood for you).